# Ionic Live Update (App Update Plugin)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I tried to implement this plugin and feature on my project but the documentation is too poor, and all the tutorials on internet are using a Cordova Hot Code Push plugin.

Unfortunately the installation of **Cordova Hot Code Push CLI client**, used by every single tutorial on internet about it, keeps getting an error on:
*cordova hot code push error postinstall*

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ngrok@2.3.0 postinstall: `node ./postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ngrok@2.3.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/midias14/.npm/_logs/2018-06-06T19_45_57_204Z-debug.log
```

And not being able to resolve, I'm trying to implement hard way.

Any help on doing by hand?

I'm on Ionic3, Ubuntu sys.

Comment: did you follow recent webinar/livestream - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7PC3O4q1ug - was it also not helpful?

Comment: also what specifically you found poor? https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/plugin-api.html - i did follow this tutorial and things worked (at that time) for me so I am not sure what do you mean. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko of course it is helpful my friend :) But only if you PAY for it. The deploy service of Ionic Pro its the best tool for this task. But the price and use conditions aren't very friendly... The "free" option provided on ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-update it's poooorly documented and even the github repository s horrible. Well... I really appreciate your response, but I'd rather keep looking another way o/

Comment: Ahh sorry didn't know about it to be paid for. As I used it when we I guess had subscription;/ then yes this is tricky...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue yesterday. Try install the plugin with flag `--unsafe-perm=true`.